# properties of sums and product of functions

Tags: functions

There is this question in my book: if $f$, $g$, $h$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then show that $$(f+g)\circ h=f\circ h+g\circ h$$

The proof in my book goes like this:
$$(f+g)\circ h
    =(f+g).h(x)
    =f(h(x))+g(h(x))
    =f\circ h+g\circ h$$
I can't understand the transition from the second step to the third one, i.e. how can I prove this:
$$(f+g).h(x)=f(h(x))+g(h(x))$$

Also is $(f+g)\circ h=f\circ h+g\circ h$ always true for any three functions or are some specific conditions necessary for it to be true?

Answer (score 4):

By definition of composition, for any $x$ in its domain

$$[(f+g)\circ h](x)=(f+g)(h(x))$$

By definition (of the sum of functions):

$$(f+g)(h(x))=f(h(x))+g(h(x))$$

Finally, by definition of composition:

$$f(h(x))+g(h(x))=(f\circ h) (x)+(g\circ h) (x)$$

The result is true of any three functions where the compositions work (i.e. with the appropriate domains and codomains). In this case the domain and codomain are both $\mathbb{R}$, so this is guaranteed.

Comment: is it possible to prove (f+g)(h(x))=f(h(x))+g(h(x)) ?i'm confused.

Comment: There isn't anything to prove there because that is just how the (pointwise) sum of two functions is defined. Maybe it's worth recalling that that $h(x)$ is just a real number, so you could write it more simply as $y=h(x)$. Then do you see why it is true?

Comment: so that is just how it is defined ..thank you  so much.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth pointing out that statements like "$f(h(x))+g(h(x))=f\circ h + g\circ h$" don't make sense, because on the left hand side you have a real number and on the right hand side you have a function.